# Flutter app for iOS: 'Rate My App' works on device when installed from computer but does not work when installed from TestFlight

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I develope App in Flutter and encounter the following problem:
When I install the app on real device from computer, rate-my-app works well (Also on Simulator is good). The window with starts pops up. However, when I install the same app from TestFlight, rate-my-app function is dead. Nothing happens. The window with starts does not pop up. Very wired. What could be the problem?

Here is Class for Rate:

```
class RateAppInitWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget Function(RateMyApp) builder;
  const RateAppInitWidget({Key key, this.builder}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _RateAppInitWidgetState createState() => _RateAppInitWidgetState();
}

class _RateAppInitWidgetState extends State<RateAppInitWidget> {

  RateMyApp rateMyApp;

  /// Rate App-------------------------
  List<Widget> actionBuilder(BuildContext context, double stars) {
    return stars == null
    ? [buildCancelButton()]
    : [buildOkButton(stars), buildCancelButton()];
  }
  Widget buildOkButton(double starNumber) {
    final event = RateMyAppEventType.rateButtonPressed;
    rateMyApp.callEvent(event);

    if (starNumber >= 4.0) {
      return RateMyAppRateButton(
        rateMyApp,
        text: 'Ok',
      );
    } else {
      Utils.openEmail(
          toEmail: 'sttaaat@gmail.com',
          subject: 'App',
          body: 'Hi developers!');
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
      return Container();
    }

  }
  Widget buildCancelButton() {
    return RateMyAppNoButton(
      rateMyApp,
      text: 'Cancel',
    );
  }
  /// Rate App-------------------------

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => RateMyAppBuilder(
      rateMyApp: RateMyApp(
        googlePlayIdentifier: packageNameAndroid,
        appStoreIdentifier: packageNameIOS,
        minDays: 5, 
        minLaunches: 5,
        remindDays: 2,
        remindLaunches: 5
      ),
    onInitialized: (context, rateMyApp) {
        setState(() => this.rateMyApp = rateMyApp);

        if (rateMyApp.shouldOpenDialog) {
          rateMyApp.showStarRateDialog(
              context,
              title: 'What do you think?',
              message: 'Please rate our App',
              starRatingOptions: StarRatingOptions(initialRating: 5),
              actionsBuilder: actionBuilder);
        }
    },
    builder: (context) => rateMyApp == null
      ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
      : widget.builder(rateMyApp)
  );
}
```

// This is the button to call:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Divider(color: Colors.black38, height: 5.0),
        ListTile(
          leading: Icon(Icons.rate_review),
          title: Text('Rate App'),
          onTap: () => widget.rateMyApp.showStarRateDialog(
              context,
              title: 'What do you think?',
              message: 'Please rate our App',
              starRatingOptions: StarRatingOptions(initialRating: 5),
              actionsBuilder: actionBuilder),
        ),
```

Comment: What is happening in your main function? It's really hard to say what your issue is without seeing any code.

Comment: just now added a code

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that rate_my_app calls the underlying native iOS method `requestReview(in:)` -- but this method is disabled if the app is installed using TestFlight.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstorereviewcontroller/3566727-requestreview

`When your app calls this method while it’s in development mode, StoreKit always displays the rating and review request view, so you can test the user interface and experience. However, this method has no effect in apps that you distribute for beta testing using TestFlight.`

Answer (score -1):

Note down following steps to avoid bugs in realise build:

-> Ignore warnings

-> Follow widget tree property

-> Ignore incorect use of parent data warning

-> Ignore Warning when use expanded

Comment: Hi Dipak, thanks for your tips. Frankly, they do not take me any further. Would you please be a bit more specific? The fragment of code is there. Do you see anything wrong there? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I mean ignore unnecessary warnings in your app